# Not able to Access Object

Tags: angular, typescript

```
this.deleteValue = {
            LanguageId : '',
            LanguageName : '',
            LongName : '',
            CreatedBy : '',
            UpdatedBy : '',
            CreatedDate : '',
            UpdateDate : '',
            IsDeleted : ''
        }
```

has been initialized in my component. I have assigned the value in one of my functions.

```
beginDel(delValue){
        this.deleteValue = new language(delValue.LanguageId, delValue.LanguageName, delValue.LongName, delValue.CreatedBy, delValue.UpdatedBy,delValue.CreatedDate,delValue.UpdateDate, delValue.IsDeleted);  
        console.log(this.deleteValue);  

    }
```

However, when I am try to access it in some other function, it is an empty object.

```
 recordDel(){
        console.log(this.deleteValue);
}
```

I think the issue is with scoping, but I'm not able to figure out what the issue is, exactly.

Comment: How can we know the details of your scoping with the data you provided us?

Comment: Who is calling `recordDel` and `beginDel` and how?

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

you re-initialized it in  beginDel. Try to call this method from inside beginDel, like this :

```
 beginDel(delValue){
     ....
     ....    
     // add chain-call here
     recordDel();
}
```